# The uniqueness of an ordinary ODE

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to show the uniqueness of a solution:

> **problem** Let $f$ Lipschitz continuous $(I\times R;R)$. Further let $k\in C^0(I\times I,R)$. Show that for $y\in C^1(I)$ and $\forall t\in I$
>   $$y'(t)=f(t,y(t))+\int_{t_0}^t k(t,s)y(s)\mathrm{d}s$$
>   the solution is unique.

My attempt: By Lipschitz continuity there exist a constant $L$

$$\leq L\int_{t_0}^t d(t)+\int_{t_0}^t \beta(s)d(t)\mathrm{d}s \mathrm{d}t$$
where $\beta(s)=(t-t_0)\cdot \max_{t\in I}k(t,s)$

But how can I show that this goes to $0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [Gronwall's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall's_inequality)

which will tell you that
$$d(t)\le d(t_0)\exp\left(\int_{t_0}^t(L+\beta(s))\,ds\right)$$

Comment: you have $d(s)$ and not $d(t)$ namely $$\int_{t_0}^t \int_{t_0}^t\beta(s)d(s)\,dsdt$$ Assume that $I$ is a bounded interval, then you can bound the last integral with $$C \int_{t_0}^t\beta(s)d(s)\,ds$$. Also your $\beta$ should be $\beta(s)=(b-a)\max_t |k(s,t)|$ where $I=[a,b]$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help